# Using LWJGL 3 with NetBeans - linking errors

Tags: java, netbeans, lwjgl

I've downloaded LWJGL 3, added the lwjgl.jar to the library list, and set the VM arguments to

`-Djava.library.path="D:/Programming/lwjgl/native/windows"`

I tried to run their "Hello World" application from http://www.lwjgl.org/guide, and I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWKeyCallback
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. It might be because there is no /windows folder in /native, just a few .dlls.

Comment: In LWJGL3 the /windows folder has two subfolders, /x64 and /x86, which contain the .dlls. Maybe you have to set java.library.path to include the specific subfolder, because /windows itself does no contain any .dlls.

Comment: In LWJGL, it's generally a good idea to set the native directory at runtime: `System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", "D:/programming/lwjgl/native/windows/32");` That way, you can detect what operating system the program is running on and set it to a different path depending on that.